# Comparing 2 revisions with svn diff (v 1.3.2) and get the changed paths only?

Tags: svn, diff

I want to compare 2 revisions using version 1.3.2 of svn and copy the changed files/folders to some place on the server. The copying is not the problem, what I have trouble with is getting only the changed paths. I am using this command:

```
svn diff -r 90:93 URL --username name --password password
```

This returns me a lot of information, how would I extract only the changed paths from that info? The --summarize is not available for version 1.3.2. What I want is something like:

*/path/test.txt*

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 14):

Are you on Unix/Linux/Mac, or have Cygwin installed?

You could pipe the output through `grep` to find all the lines that begin with `Index:`. (If I remember Subversion 1.3's diff command output) That would give you just the names of the files that differ. It's what I use to do with CVS.

```
$ svn diff -r 90:93 --username name --password password URL | grep "^Index: "
```

If that works, and you want to remove Index, you can use `sed`:

```
$ svn diff -r 90:93 --username name --password password URL \
> | sed -n /^Index: /s/^Index: //p'
```

Comment: Many `sed` implementations (all?) allow `/str/s//rpl/` as a shorthand for `/str/s/str/rpl/`